# How to remove 0 comments text from sidebar?

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am making a wordpress website but i need to remove the "0 comments" text.
I did disable comments from discussion section but I'm not able to remove the text from the sidebar.
How should I do this?

[Sidebar image of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDk4S.jpg)

Comment: edit the associated wordpress template/template tag, find inside your themes templates or functions.php

Comment: Either you can completely remove it as @NikosM. said. Another trick is , to make it archive you can just edit its CSS. Grab the class of Comments section, and write display: none. In future if you want it, you can simply make it to display:block.

Comment: @noobprogrammer answer is the correct way. Hide it with CSS.